# wp.media.view.ImageDetails - Save settings as HTML5 data-* attributes for image

Tags: plugins, images, media, html5

**What I finally want to achieve are extra settings added to the Image Details box, that will be stored in the image `<img>` tag as `data-*` attributes**

**Example:** `<img src="..." data-my_setting="...">`

---

### MY CODE

I am creating a plugin, and I need to create more settings for when you edit images. So far I have the following code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var imageDetails = wp.media.view.ImageDetails

    wp.media.view.ImageDetails = wp.media.view.ImageDetails.extend({
        // Initialize - Call function to add settings when rendered
        initialize: function() {
            this.on('post-render', this.add_settings);
        },
        // To add the Settings
        add_settings: function() {
            $('.advanced-section').prepend('\
                <h2>My Settings</h2>\
                <input type="text" class="my_setting">\
            ');

            // Set Options
            this.controller.image.set({"data-settings": 'setting-value-here'})
        }
    });

}) // End of jQuery(function($))
```

I created a new post and added one image, then clicked on it and pressed Edit (the pencil icon in the toolbar that popped up). I ended up on the image details page, and this is what it looked like:

[image]

So far, so good. On this line:

`this.controller.image.set({"data-settings": 'setting-value-here'})`

I would normally use jQuery to get the value of the input, but for testing purposes I changed it to be a static value of `'setting-value-here'`. I pressed 'Update' in the bottom-right corner of the Image Details box.

---

### THE PROBLEM

In the Text editor, it shows the HTML code as this:

[image]

This **does not** have a `data-settings="setting-value-here"`, how come?

If I replace the line with this:

```
 this.controller.image.set({alt: 'setting-value-here'})
```

It **does** change the **ALT** tag to `alt="setting-value-here"`. So what am I doing wrong trying to set the data-* attribute?

---

### THE SOLUTION

Thanks to [**@bonger**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/57034/bonger) (who got the full bounty of 50 Reputation), I have the following code:

**PHP:**

```
function add_my_settings() {
    ob_start();
    wp_print_media_templates();
    $tpl = ob_get_clean();
    if ( ( $idx = strpos( $tpl, 'tmpl-image-details' ) ) !== false
            && ( $before_idx = strpos( $tpl, '<div class="advanced-section">', $idx ) ) !== false ) {
        ob_start();
        ?>
        <div class="my_setting-section">
            <h2><?php _e( 'My Settings' ); ?></h2>
            <div class="my_setting">
                <label class="setting my_setting">
                    <span><?php _e( 'My Setting' ); ?></span>
                        <input type="text" data-setting="my_setting" value="{{ data.model.my_setting }}" />
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php
        $my_section = ob_get_clean();
        $tpl = substr_replace( $tpl, $my_section, $before_idx, 0 );
    }
    echo $tpl;
};

// Hack the output of wp_print_media_templates()
add_action('wp_enqueue_media', $func =
    function() {
        remove_action('admin_footer', 'wp_print_media_templates');
        add_action('admin_footer',  'add_my_settings');
    }
);
```

**JavaScript:** (Needs to be enqueued using `wp_enqueue_script()`)

```
// When Image is Edited
wp.media.events.on('editor:image-edit', function(data) {
    data.metadata.my_setting = data.editor.dom.getAttrib( data.image, 'data-my_setting' );
});

// When Image is Updated
wp.media.events.on('editor:image-update', function(data) {
    data.editor.dom.setAttrib( data.image, 'data-my_setting', data.metadata.my_setting );
});
```

Comment: I wish I could +2 - eloquent, concise, well researched, so on-topic it hurts. Questions like these are a rare breed.

Comment: Thanks! I always try and research (and extensively debug) my problems as much as I can before I ask. (I hate it when you find a really simple question and the OP hasn't even tried Googling)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A way to do it is to use the (very convenient) `editor:image-edit` and `editor:image-update` events triggered by the tinymce `wpeditimage` plugin to get/set the dom directly (**updated** to wrap in `wp_enqueue_media` action):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_media', function () {
    add_action( 'admin_footer', function () {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            if (wp && wp.media && wp.media.events) {
                wp.media.events.on( 'editor:image-edit', function (data) {
                    data.metadata.my_setting = data.editor.dom.getAttrib( data.image, 'data-my_setting' );
                } );
                wp.media.events.on( 'editor:image-update', function (data) {
                    data.editor.dom.setAttrib( data.image, 'data-my_setting', data.metadata.my_setting );
                } );
            }
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }, 11 );
} );
```

To add and populate the settings field, it's perhaps groovier to hack the output of `wp_print_media_templates()` rather than override `ImageDetails.initialize()` (**updated** to wrap in `wp_enqueue_media` action):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_media', function () {
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_print_media_templates' );
    add_action( 'admin_footer', $func = function () {
        ob_start();
        wp_print_media_templates();
        $tpl = ob_get_clean();
        // To future-proof a bit, search first for the template and then for the section.
        if ( ( $idx = strpos( $tpl, 'tmpl-image-details' ) ) !== false
                && ( $before_idx = strpos( $tpl, '<div class="advanced-section">', $idx ) ) !== false ) {
            ob_start();
            ?>
    <div class="my_setting-section">
        <h2><?php _e( 'My Settings' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="my_setting">
            <label class="setting my_setting">
                <span><?php _e( 'My Setting' ); ?></span>
                <input type="text" data-setting="my_setting" value="{{ data.model.my_setting }}" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
            <?php
            $my_section = ob_get_clean();
            $tpl = substr_replace( $tpl, $my_section, $before_idx, 0 );
        }
        echo $tpl;
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This a very useful (though it takes a few minutes to get your head around). I'll accept the answer and award the bounty to you just before it ends (someone my come up with a better/simpler answer)

Comment: Hmm, that will happen if it's run before `wp_enqueue_media()` is. Perhaps a nicer way is to use the `wp_enqueue_media` action that is fired at the end of `wp_enqueue_media()`, ie wrap all the code in an `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_media', function () { /*the code*/ } );`

Comment: No, vice versa!

Comment: I'll update the answer...

Comment: Wait, do not worry, it works! I use SE too much, I used `\`` instead of `'`. Thanks for the help, full bounty awarded to you!

Comment: Just made a similar mistake myself updating the answer!

Comment: Actually, one more question. What is this, and where is the documentation: `{{ data.model.my_setting }}`. It looks a bit like AngularJS code. I found out about PHP code inside one set of curly brackets but not two. And should it not be `{{ $data.model.my_setting }}` (with a `$`)?

Comment: It's WP's override of underscore's template stuff http://underscorejs.org/#template (see `wp.template` in "wp-includes/js/wp-util.js").... I think